# Install own Apps on a iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes

I want to make an App for the iPhone, but want to deploy it inside another App - not via the store. Is there any possibility to do that?

Sorry for the stupid question, but I am a Android developer and have no clue about iPhone and iOS.

Thanks

Comment: Nope, apple only let's you submit apps through the app store.  However, if you know the person that wrote the app, and they want to personally configure your project within their app, they could do that and submit it in the form of an update. Note: I don't know what the deal is for jailbroken phones.

Comment: ... so you want to make two apps for the iPhone?

Comment: Ok, Thanks - I thought there is a way to update it like on Android, by enabling "Install App's from other places" setting

Answer (score 1):

If you are an iPhone developer (you have payed the $100 fee and signed up with apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action)) then you can build apps that you make to your phone. Other than that, the only way to install an app without going through the app store is if you are using a jailbroken phone.